# How do i fix the array index out of range?

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting the currently playing song and storing its title in an array named `arrayOfSongs`, then I am extracting any repeating song titles, and creating a new array `uniqueTitle`, which will only have the title of a song once even if it is played more than once. Whenever I click the next button to go to the next song, the title text will be added to the cell, and added to the array, but if I go back to a song that has already been added to the array I get an error `Array index out of range`. I think I know why I am getting the error, the program is trying to add the title to the cell, but since I am adding the unique array, if I go back to a repeated song it is not added to the array an the program will try to add that non existent title. How do I solve this?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 


    //function to remove repeating objects
    func uniq<S : SequenceType, T : Hashable where S.Generator.Element == T>(source: S) -> [T] {
        var buffer = [T]()
        var added = Set<T>()
        for elem in source {
            if !added.contains(elem) {
                buffer.append(elem)
                added.insert(elem)

            }
        }
        return buffer
    }
    var uniqueTitle = uniq(arrayOfSongs)
    print(uniqueTitle)

    cell.textLabel?.text = uniqueTitle[indexPath.row]
    return cell
```

Comment: Yeah is there any way to fix this?

Comment: If I correctly understand you should remove duplicates before table view is drawn .. override method which takes the number of rows in the table
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  arrayLengthWithoutDuplicates
    }

Comment: Once I put the function outside the table view function I can't access the `uniqueTitle` array.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow, so should I move the unique function outside of the tableview function? and what do you mean by move the property uniqueTitle into my class?

Comment: move property `var uniqueTitle` outside of method `func tableView`
then   `var uniqueTitle` will be accessible from any method of your your class. which is used to build tableView

Comment: http://puu.sh/kUgZa/dcddd840ae.png

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1QsyvV42